# Evaluate/compare NSString with wildcards?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, wildcard

Hi
I'm trying to evaluate an NSString to see if it fits a certain criteria, which contains wildcards in the form of one or more asterix characters.

Example:

```
NSString *filePath = @"file://Users/test/Desktop/file.txt";
NSString *matchCriteria = @"file://*/file.*";
```

I would like to see if `filePath` matches (fits?) `matchCriteria`, in this example it does.
Does anybody know how I can go about doing this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to `NSRegularExpression`, you can also use [`NSPredicate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html).

```
NSString *filePath = @"file://Users/test/Desktop/file.txt";
NSString *matchCriteria = @"file://*/file.*";

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self LIKE %@", matchCriteria];

BOOL filePathMatches = [pred evaluateWithObject:filePath];
```

The [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) is a comprehensive document desribing how predicates work. They can be particularly useful if you have an array of items that you want to filter based on some criteria.

Answer (score 4):

NSString implements these methods:

```
@interface NSObject (NSComparisonMethods)
- (BOOL)isLike:(NSString *)object;
- (BOOL)isCaseInsensitiveLike:(NSString *)object;
@end
```

They are much faster than NSPredicate and NSRegularExpression.

Comment: This is really interesting, never knew about those. It seems however that `NSComparisonMethods` is only available on Mac OS X, not on iOS.

Comment: For general interest - the NSComparisonMethods category provides many more convenience comparisons, and is part of the AppleScript support (NSScriptWhoseTest.h) in Foundation. Really fast and useful. Good catch @Elden!